# NSURLProtocol not responding to UIWebviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, nsurlprotocol

I am having an issue with **UIWebviews** and a couple of custom **NSURLProtocols** that I have in my app.

All my **non** web view request are invoked with NSURLSession, so in order for those request to go through the protocols I need to set the `setProtocolClasses` array on my sessionconfig, at this point everything works as expected.
For my web views, I do a registration on the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method in the AppDelegate with the `[NSURLProtocol register class[MyProtocol Class]]`. If i don't re-register before the execution of the web view request, that web view request won't go through the protocol.

Do you guys have any idea why I have to re-register to my custom protocol every time I try to load a web view request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the request URL?  Is it possible that there's another protocol class that gets registered after you?  Does `canInitWithRequest` get called on your class at webview request time?

Comment: What a good catch! I guess the last protocol to register is the first to fire?